# ODATA method design pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to OData although familiar with WebAPI routing...

I have two collections USERS and TEAMS with their controllers constructed from EF6. From both I can return all the users or a single

```
USERS
http://localhost:50798/odata/members
http://localhost:50798/odata/members(1)

TEAMS
http://localhost:50798/odata/teams
http://localhost:50798/odata/teams(1)
```

I need to return the team on a specific member ID. Through OData the method name is ignored and what I instinctively want to do is put a method in the teams controller, say "GetTeamFromMember", it then join from the users collection to the teams collection and return the single team.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific methods called functions with OData but what you are doing here is perfect for OData navigation properties. You can navigate relationships from entities. For example, the URL for what you are trying to do here could then be:

```
http://localhost:50798/odata/members(1)/team
```

Comment: Here is a link for setting up navigation properties: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4 and here for functions: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions